# How to change Cluster Queue Manager status from running to inactive, and change from inactive to running

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq

As below display, I need to change the Cluster Queue Manager(not the queue manager) from INACTIVE to Running. And after it is changed to Running, what command should I use if I need to change it from Running to Inactive. Anyone can tell me the command on this? Thanks!

```
DISPLAY CLUSQMGR (PWRCSHK03) STATUS
     8 : DISPLAY CLUSQMGR (PWRCSHK03) STATUS
AMQ8441: Display Cluster Queue Manager details.
   CLUSQMGR(PWRCSHK03)                     CHANNEL(TO.PWRCSHK03.PHK02)
   CLUSTER(PHKCLUS02)                      STATUS(INACTIVE)
DISPLAY QMSTATUS
     9 : DISPLAY QMSTATUS
AMQ8705: Display Queue Manager Status Details.
   QMNAME(PWRCSHK03)                       STATUS(RUNNING)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `STATUS` shown  on a `CLUSQMGR` is the status of the channel. So when you see `STATUS(INACTIVE)` this means that the channel isn't running.

The channel will start running automatically when it has messages to deliver - one of the benefits of clustering, but if you really want to start it up, assuming it is a `CLUSSDR` channel, you can use:-

```
START CHANNEL(TO.PWRCSHK03.PHK02)
```

If it is a `CLUSRCVR` then to see `STATUS(RUNNING)` you need to start one of the `CLUSSDR` channels on another queue manager in the cluster to connect to this queue manager's `CLUSRCVR`.